# Anyone remember the name of this iOS sharing app?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, sharing

A long time ago, there was an iOS app that was quite innovative for the time. The way it worked was that two iDevices on the same Wi-Fi network that wanted to share data (for instance a picture) would launch this app and come to a virtual "table". The edge of the table would be a recipient. To send the picture, the sender would choose what to share and bring it to the table, and then swipe the picture off a particular edge of the screen, and it would slide in on the recipient's device. As far as I can recall, the UI was white.

Can anyone name this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Mover](https://web.archive.org/web/20110926173921/http://infinite-labs.net/mover/)

> Put something — a contact, a photo, a video, a file — on the Mover table, connect two iOS or Mac OS X thingies to the same Wi-Fi network and slide away. It's that simple, really.
>   (Yep, you can also use Bluetooth between iPhones, iPod touches and iPads, if you're on the go!)

∞labs, the developer of Mover, shut down a while ago and the app is no longer available.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much for taking the time to reply, have a nice day!